# Elasticsearch How to sort by length of list

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to sort a search by the length of a list. I have a field defined by

```
"authors": { 
    "type": "text", "norms": { "enabled": False }, "analyzer": "autocomplete_with_asciifolding", "search_analyzer": "with_and_without_accent_search", "position_increment_gap": 100,
    "fields": {
        "raw" : { # This field is needed for your_paper suggestions search
            "type" : "string",
            "analyzer" : 'lower_keyword'
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to sort by this field, which might look like ['John Doe', 'Mike Smith']

Following the elasticsearch documentation and some google searches I found

```
doc['sort'] = { 
            "_script": {  
                "type": "number", 
                "script": "doc['authors'].length",
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
```

I also tried doc['authors'].values.length() and doc['authors'].values.size(), but all of them result in

```
TransportError: TransportError(500, u'search_phase_execution_exception')
```

any idea how to sort by the length of a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access to `doc['authors']` because [field data is disabled in text fields by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#_fielddata_is_disabled_on_literal_text_literal_fields_by_default) for performance reasons.

You can, for example, set fielddata=true in your inner field `raw`:

```
"authors": { 
    "type": "text", "norms": { "enabled": False }, "analyzer": "autocomplete_with_asciifolding", "search_analyzer": "with_and_without_accent_search", "position_increment_gap": 100,
    "fields": {
        "raw" : { # This field is needed for your_paper suggestions search
            "type" : "string",
            "analyzer" : 'lower_keyword',
            "fielddata": True
        }
    }
}
```

And sort by `authors.raw` instead:

```
doc['sort'] = { 
            "_script": {  
                "type": "number", 
                "script": "doc['authors.raw'].length",
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
```

Another solution would be to create a new inner field of type `keyword` and sort by it. But I suggested to use `raw` because it looks that analyzer just lower the case.